# I need help with choosing a computer on the board

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I need a computer on the board like raspberry pi for vending machine (I want to replace the original controller). This is list of some requirements:

1) It should have pins to connect to the [mdb protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidrop_bus) & other stuff through gpio.

2) Good performance. There will be a display with browser showing rails application running. I've tried a raspberry pi B+, but it's too slow (it can't even run a browser with speed like a laptop pc). So, I want to choose a more powerful system like odroid, wandboard etc.

3) Custom video output. Sometimes I need to display FullHD(1920x1080), sometimes I need to show at 768x1024 (yes, the computer should simply rotate video output)

4) I don't want to connect microcomputer to display directly, not through HDMI, DVI or something like this. (This is not required, but very desirable).

Please help me choose. Nowadays I try to choose from odroid, wandboard or pandaboard. Are there any other computers? What version of the computer is advisable?

Answer (score 1):

Nevertheless I can only recommend the Nvidia Jetson TK1 board!
https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-tk1

Great performance, cheap and with GPIO and HDMI.
Perfect support for Ubuntu Linux.

BTW: I don't get your point 4)

Comment: Playing fullHD videos on jetson tk1 is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend

1. Nvidia TK1
2. Odroid XU3

Both have GPIO that you can program. And both have a desktop version Linux (or Android, in Odroid XU3).

Odroid XU3 can set display video size in boot script. I don't know about TK1.

Your point 4) can be achieved by using VNC. Basically you can use your laptop to view the display from your board. Here is a tutorial for setting VNC:
[VNC Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I strongly recommend VNC.

Comment: Paul, what do you mean by `set video inputs in boot script`

Comment: Sorry! I mean video output. You can set video output to 640x480 or 1920x1080, something like this